# What do I use in place of CameraX.bindToLifecycle(lifeCycleOwner, preview, imageCapture) now?

Tags: android, camera, android-camerax

I'm trying to create an android application that uses a camera and want to release the related objects when I need to. I'm following someone else's repository who used the bindToLifecycle(lifeCycleOwner, imageCapture, preview) for the same but now that the method is deprecated, I'm looking for replacements.

I thought I'd just manually destroy the imageCapture and preview objects but am finding that hard to do. How does one destroy the imageCapture objects manually? What exactly is the standard way to do this in place of bindToLifecycle?

Comment: The current method: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/lifecycle/ProcessCameraProvider#bindToLifecycle(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector,androidx.camera.core.UseCase...)